# Buggy (?) compiler behaviors when instantiating a member template function

Tags: c++

Edit - The exact minimal code to test this *was* in my original post below, but it is two chunks.  My apologies, here it is in one piece.  Commenting out the instantiations in `main` and then uncommenting them one at a time shows the behavior I describe in this post.

```
template <typename... TsOuter>
struct Outer
{
    template <TsOuter...>
    static void InnerFunc() {};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1, 1>();              // Should work.  Works on MSVC, fails on g++
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc();                    // Should fail.  Works on both compilers
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<>();                  // Should fail.  Works on both compilers
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1>();                 // Should fail.  Works on MSVC, fails on g++
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1, 1, 1>();           // Should fail.  Fails on both compilers
    Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<nullptr, nullptr>();  // Should fail.  Fails on both compilers.
}
```

Edit - I failed to include the compiler versions I am using, with which I see the behavior I describe:

- gcc: 7.3.0
- MSVC: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, version 15.7.4

I am seeing compiler behaviors that I believe are wrong - in both Microsoft C++ and g++.  The compilers give errors when I believe they should compile successfully, and they compile successfully when I believe they should give errors.  The buggy (?) compiler behaviors are not exactly the same between the two compilers.

**My question is:  are the compilers indeed buggy, or is there a bug in my understanding somewhere?  Does the spec say that compiler behavior for the code below is undefined?**

The issue occurs when a template class with a template parameter that is a parameter pack defines a member function template *that uses the class's parameter pack as its template parameter*.  When I instantiate that member function template

- I get errors in cases when its template arguments correctly match the definition of its template parameters
- And vice-versa: I compile successfully when its template arguments do not match its template parameters.

And what is weird, if the member template is a member template *class* instead of a member template function, everything works exactly as I expect.

Here is the template class definition:

```
template <typename... TsOuter>
struct Outer
{
    template <TsOuter...>
    struct InnerClass {};

    template <TsOuter...>
    static void InnerFunc() {};
};
```

Notice the template parameters of `InnerClass` and `InnerFunc` depend on the template arguments of `Outer`.

I instantiate `Outer` as `Outer<int, int>`.  That makes the declaration of `InnerClass`

```
template <int,int>
struct InnerClass {};
```

and the declaration of `InnerFunc`

```
template <int, int>
static void InnerFunc() {};
```

When instantiating `InnerClass`, the compilers' behavior (both MSVC and g++) matches my understanding:

```
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass<1, 1> x2 {};              // OK
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass x2 {};                    // ERROR - No template arguments provided for InnerClass
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass<> x2 {};                  // ERROR - <> does not match <int, int> (to few template arguments)
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass<1> x1 {};                 // ERROR - <1> does not match <int, int> (to few template arguments)
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass<1, 1, 1> x3 {};           // ERROR - <1,1,1> does not match <int, int> (to many template arguments)
Outer<int, int>::InnerClass<nullptr, nullptr> x4 {};  // ERROR - <nullptr, nullptr> does not match <int, int> (template argument types do not match template parameter types)
```

However, with `InnerFunction` it is different.  My expectations for `InnerFunction` are the same for `InnerClass`.  But what I see is:

```
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1,1>();               // Should work.  Works on MSVC, fails on g++
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc();                    // Should fail.  Works on both compilers
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<>();                  // Should fail.  Works on both compilers
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1>();                 // Should fail.  Works on MSVC, fails on g++
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1,1,1>();             // Should fail.  Fails on both compilers
Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<nullptr, nullptr>();  // Should fail.  Fails on both compilers.
```

If `Outer` has non-variadic template parameter(s), I don't see this issue - everything works as expected for both `InnerClass` and `InnerFunction`.

Given the behavior of the compilers that I describe here, am I correct that they both have bugs?  If so they seem like pretty significant bugs to me.

Thanks!

Comment: What compiler versions? What platform specifically? What language standard? What error messages? Also, can you post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, that other people can test?

Comment: btw the first two paragraphs dont add much to the question, if you add the `language-lawyer` tag you can remove them, because it conveys the same message

Comment: 999 times out of 1000 it is not the compiler being buggy, it's you misunderstanding what the compiler is doing or what it's supposed to be doing. Presuming a compiler bug as the cause of your problems leads to nothing but misunderstanding and confusion.

Comment: To be fair, the OP does say quite clearly _" ... or is there a bug in my understanding somewhere? Does the spec say that compiler behavior for the code below is undefined?"_

Comment: @JoeyMallone Sure, but there's still a lot of needed information missing. As it stands, I'd say the question is unanswerable.

Comment: In my opinion, the only case, where one could jump to the conclusion, that the bug is in the compiler, is when you get a "Compiler internal error". If one manages to find a compiler that compiles your code, while there are compilers that don't - one has a question: "Which compiler behaves correctly?". If all compilers, you managed to get your hands on, reject such code, the first possibility on the list is: you misunderstood something, since it's very unlikely, that all vendors managed to make a bug in (essentially), exactly the same place.

Comment: @Jesper - Sorry that I failed to include the compiler versions.  I added them at the top of the post.  I came close to providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example...the only thing was it was in two separate `Code` chunks in the post.  I could have done better and I added a complete example in a single `Code` chunk at the top of the post.

Comment: @tadman, and also Algirdas - I am absolutely *not* presuming anything or jumping to conclusions.  In my original post, in bold, I said "My question is: are the compilers indeed buggy, or is there a bug in my understanding somewhere?".  I am happy either way, in fact I would prefer the latter since I would learn something and fixing the compilers is out of scope for me.  Sorry, but it seems like *you* are assuming that I was assuming buggy compilers - despite the fact that I clearly say that there might be a bug in my understanding.  You are meta-assuming.

Comment: Also to beat this dead horse: since in some cases the two compilers (MSVC and g++) give different results (successful compile vs. failed compile), then either the code is undefined behavior, or at least one of the compilers has a bug.  That's logical, right?  And again, in my original post, I explicitly ask whether I have a bug in my understanding or the code yields undefined behavior.  <PassiveAggressive> Maybe someone could help me rather than judge me unfairly. </PassiveAggressive>

Comment: If this is a bug it's worth boiling this down to a minimal case that can be forwarded to the respective compiler teams for confirmation and bug-fixing. The reason we're generally cynical about compiler bugs is because it's rarely ever a compiler bug. If it proves to be one in this case that's quite an achievement.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a compiler error in gcc.

The following was used to test

https://godbolt.org/z/8ZZt-B

```
template <typename... TsOuter>
struct Outer
{
    template <TsOuter... n>
    static void InnerFunc() {
        static int i[2] = { n... };
    };
};

int main() {
    typedef Outer<int, int> t;

    t::InnerFunc<1, 1>();
}
```

This compiles fine in clang and msvc.

But in gcc the error is:

```
<source>:13:24: error: no matching function for call to 'Outer<int, int>::InnerFunc<1, 1>()'
   13 |     t::InnerFunc<1, 1>();
      |                        ^
<source>:5:17: note: candidate: 'template<TsOuter ...n> static void Outer<TsOuter>::InnerFunc() [with TsOuter ...n = {n ...}; TsOuter = {int, int}]'
    5 |     static void InnerFunc() {
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:13:24: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
   13 |     t::InnerFunc<1, 1>();
      |                        ^
```

Which suggests that gcc thinks that there should be one argument, not 2, mistakenly not expanding the parameter pack.

And if you do actually pass one argument instead of 2:

https://godbolt.org/z/9fZZZC

```
t::InnerFunc<1>();
```

```
<source>:13:21: internal compiler error: tree check: accessed elt 1 of tree_vec with 0 elts in tsubst_pack_expansion, at cp/pt.c:12169
   13 |     t::InnerFunc<1>();
      |                     ^
```

I'm not actually sure how parameter packs as template parameters is supposed to work, but it definitely shouldn't be an internal compiler error. I couldn't reproduce this on a local g++ install, but the error wierdly cuts off (Printing "template argument deduction/substitution failed:" and then nothing)